# Objective-C Overriding method in subclass with different parameter type

Tags: objective-c, parameters, overriding, subclass

Here below the definitions of two classes (Foo and Bar) and two respective subclasses (SubFoo and SubBar). Foo is a kind of a dummy class and Bar has a method that takes a Foo instance as a parameter:

```
@interface Foo
@end

@interface SubFoo : Foo
@end


@interface Bar

- (void)doSthWithFoo:(Foo *)aFoo;

@end

@interface SubBar : Bar

// other methods

@end
```

Implementations are skipped but consider them being straightforward.

Only then in the implementation of SubBar there is this twist:

```
@implementation SubBar

- (void)doSthWithFoo:(SubFoo *)aFoo
{
    // Do stuff with object of type *SubFoo*
}

// other methods

@end
```

In the subclass, doSthWithFoo: is overridden and the parameter type is changed to SubFoo – in place of Foo, as in the parent class. This is intentionally done so, as SubBar can only work with SubFoo's so to speak.

This compiles fine, runs fine and does not produce any warnings – kind of surprisingly I must admit. But somehow it doesn't feel very right, even though IMO it's a relatively clean way of doing things..

I am aware that a parameter of type id could be passed instead, but then I'd lose type checking (for Foo) from within Xcode. I am also aware that the same could be accomplished by assigning to id and then to the specific type or by checking and casting – although I haven't tried those options.

Is this a "legitimate" way of doing things? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: In general, Objective-C doesn't support contra- or co- variance (changing type of return value or arguments for the same method signature).   In practice, it works as long as the arguments are of the same general type/size, but you'll run into problems (like the need to cast often).   It is best to avoid doing this.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks.